# Merge [case-statement] and [case] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

TL;DR:

- Retag [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) questions to [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case)
- Make [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) a synonym of [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement)
- Reverse synonyms [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) and [case-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-expression), so the tag displayed is the latter.

---

The tags [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) and [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) are both about `CASE` in SQL. [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) states that the tag should not be about programming language `Case` [statement] questions and [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement) should be used instead. [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement), on the other hand, confusingly states *"Do not use this tag, use [switch-statement] instead."* even though it also explicitly says it's about the SQL `CASE`: *"A case statement allows sequences of SQL statements..."*

I propose that [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) should be merged into [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case). The former only has 431 questions, where as the latter 7,869. [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement), as a name, is also incorrect, as `CASE` in SQL is *not* a statement but an expression; it doesn't control the logical flow of the SQL statement but returns a scalar value. Calling it a "statement" implies it works like a programming language `Case` (`Switch`) statement, which it functionally does not.

I would also suggest that [case-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-statement) should then be made a synonym of [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement), *not* [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) to avoid the aforementioned confusion.

Ideally I would also, personally, suggest that [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) should be a synonym of [case-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-expression), rather than the other way round (to again try to avoid the aforementioned confusion) but that's more semantics.

Comment: Case is a bad tag and should not exist. People are using it for non-sql questions.

Comment: People misuse tags all the time, @Braiam , and it's why I'm proposing that it should be [[tag:case-expression]] not [[tag:case]].

Comment: Sorry, I read it backwards, that case should stay.

Comment: Retag [case-statement] as a synonym of [switch-statement], just in [case].

Comment: That's in there too, @kjhughes ;)

Comment: Yes, I support your proposal.  That comment was meant to be a title suggestion.

Comment: SQL/PSM (i.e. the ISO/ANSI SQL stored procedures) has a `case` _statement_ - which I wouldn't tag as switch-statement.

Comment: How about [sql-case] for the SQL related questions? It matches [sql-update], [sql-like], [sql-order-by], etc.

Comment: Case does not means Case when used inapporpriately.

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly no need for the separate tags about `switch` and `case` where these relate to the `switch`/`case` construct in imperative languages. In my opinion, any tags about this construct should be merged into a single tag, perhaps [switch-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-case) (currently a synonym of [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement)) is the best option since it will show up when you enter either `switch` or `case` into the tag list. This would also be consistent with how the [try-catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/try-catch) tag is named.

I didn't look very far, but it looks like quite a significant number of questions are using the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case) tag for questions about the SQL `CASE` construct, and the tag wiki does specify that that is what the tag should be used for. So I propose cleaning up that tag to remove any questions not about SQL (and retagging them where appropriate), and renaming that tag to [sql-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-case) in order to prevent further misuse.